# How to activate jquery tabs from an image map href (and the tab list as well)?

Tags: jquery, imagemap, jquery-tabs

I have tried all options I could think off and tried to find the answer in other posts.
I am trying to have jQuery tabs open on the page when clicking on image maps above the tabs.

```
$(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
});

<div id="tabs">
<map name="Map" id="Map">
<area shape="rect" onclick="$('#tabs-1').click();" coords="11,121,159,222" href="#tabs-1" target="_self" alt="tabs-1" />
<area shape="rect" onclick="$('#tabs-2').click();" coords="164,85,300,153" href="#tabs-2" target="_self" alt="tabs-2" /> </map>

  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab2</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="tabs-1">
lorem ipsum
</div>
<div id="tabs-2">
lorem est
</div>
</div>
```

The tabs show up in the url but the page needs to be reloaded in order for the tab to be active.

Comment: Wrap your function in a `$(document).ready()`

Comment: You have the use the click even of the link that activates that tab, not the click of the tab content itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is slightly off.  Your telling the `area` to trigger a click on an element with id `tabs-1` instead of clicking the tabs LINK that is supposed to activate `tabs-1`

You should change as follows:

- Give an id to your tab links (easiest way, but others are available if you want)
- call `click` on the tab link

So my HTML would look like this:

```
<div id="tabs">
<map name="Map" id="Map">
<area shape="rect" onclick="$('#tabs-1-link').click();" coords="11,121,159,222" href="#tabs-1" target="_self" alt="tabs-1" />
<area shape="rect" onclick="$('#tabs-2-link').click();" coords="164,85,300,153" href="#tabs-2" target="_self" alt="tabs-2" /> </map>

  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1" id="tabs-1-link">Tab1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2" id="tabs-1-link">Tab2</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="tabs-1">
lorem ipsum
</div>
<div id="tabs-2">
lorem est
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank You Eli !!! I knew my logic was off and could not figure out where to stick the missing id. This works perfectly well. Next step would be to build this without the clumsy image mapping.

Comment: No problem.  When SO allows you, please upvote/accept the answer for future searchers. happy coding.